# How can I determine the result in AX after MOV and LEA instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, real-mode

I am trying to understand what will be the content of *AX* register in the following question, I don't understand how I can know what [5000h] or [DI] is in the examples.

The state of the registers and memory are defined as:

```
CS=3000 [53000]=BBBB [33000]=6666 [13000]=1111
DS=1000 [54000]=CCCC [34000]=7777 [14000]=2222
SS=5000 [55000]=DDDD [35000]=8888 [15000]=3333
DI=7000 [56000]=EEEE [36000]=9999 [16000]=4444
BP=4000 [57000]=FFFF [37000]=AAAA [17000]=5555
```

What is the value in AX for each of these instructions

- `MOV AX, [DI]`
- `MOV AX, [5000h]`
- `MOV AX, [BP+2000h]`
- `LEA AX, [BP+1000h]`

Comment: Remember that there's an implicit `DS:` before `[DI]`

Comment: And an implicit `SS:` before `[BP]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an academic question, but it touches on a number of concepts of real mode [20-bit segment:offset addressing](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html). All memory addresses in real mode are always made up of two parts - a segment and an offset. The two parts are combined together to generate a physical address with the formula:

> ```
> Physical Address = segment * 16 + offset
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> Physical Address = segment << 4 + offset
> ```

Both yield the same result as shifting something left 4 bits is the same as multiplying by 16 decimal (or 10h hexadecimal).

You will find that instructions may specify a segment explicitly and when it isn't specified there is always an implicit one. A general rule is that if a memory address uses *BP* then the memory operand is relative to the *SS* segment, otherwise it is relative to the *DS* segment.

An `LEA` instruction doesn't actually access physical memory, it simply computes the effective address of the memory operand and loads the address in a register. With `LEA` the segment doesn't come into play. A `MOV` instruction with a memory operand will move the contents of a memory operand to/from a register.

---

All the values given in your questions are given in hexadecimal. To answer your questions:

- `MOV AX, [DI]` is the same as `MOV AX, [DS:DI]` since the implied segment is *DS*. In the question *DS*=1000h. *DI*=7000h . The offset is *DI*. Using the formula segment<<4 + offset we get physical address 1000h<<4+7000h = 10000h+7000h=17000h. The question states memory address `[17000]=5555` so the value moved to AX is 5555h.
- `MOV AX, [5000h]` is the same as `MOV AX, [DS:5000h]` since the implied segment is *DS*. In the question *DS*=1000h. The offset is 5000h . Using the formula segment<<4 + offset we get physical address 1000h<<4+5000h = 10000h+5000h=15000h. The question states memory address `[15000]=3333` so the value moved to AX is 3333h.
- `MOV AX, [BP+2000h]` is the same as `MOV AX, [SS:BP+2000h]` since the implied segment is *SS*. In the question *SS*=5000h and *BP*=4000h. The offset is *BP*+2000h . Using the formula segment<<4 + offset we get physical address 5000h<<4+(4000h+2000h) = 50000h+(4000h+2000h)=56000h. The question states memory address `[56000]=EEEE` so the value moved to AX is EEEEh.
- `LEA AX, [BP+1000h]` : The segment doesn't come into play since it is an `LEA` instruction. In the question *BP*=4000h. The offset is *BP*+1000h=4000h+1000h = 5000h. Since `LEA` only computes and stores the address in a register the value in *AX* will be 5000h.

Comment: +1 This answer is right where mine is wrong. You can *accept* it by checking the green mark below the upvote. The reason this answer is right is that, unlike me, @MichaelPetch remembers the details of 8086 as it was used 35 years ago. My answer is in the modern 64-bt era, which is wrong for your purpose.

Comment: @thb I honestly don't see where your answer is wrong. Yes, Michael elaborates more on the instructions that ultimately have no effect on the outcome, but other than that, you correctly stated that `LEA` just does an address calculation using the offset and the result is `5000h`.

Comment: @Jester: thank you; I had not known that. Unfortunately, if my answer was right, it was accidentally right. I really don't know the old 16-bit 8086 mode. I was thinking 64 bits.

Comment: @jester : in the assignment all those instructions are independent.It would have been better had they been labelled 1,2,3,4. It is just how the person worded the question that makes them look like a seqeunce of instructions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I see. Still, thb's answer is not wrong, just partial then. He can keep my upvote :) Especially since the question title says "the program" which strongly implies this is a single program with the given sequence of instructions. I interpreted it that way too.

Comment: @jester : I didn't say his answer was wrong. To the contrary he only happened to give a partial answer. I think what thb is saying that if he had applied his knowledge to all of the instructions he may not have arrived at the proper result for each one.

Answer (score 2):

[My answer is left here for reference but I withdraw it. From the information you have given, I gather that your x86 processor is operating in privileged 8086 compatibility mode, as during boot loading. I have no experience at writing bootloaders, unfortunately.]

Old data in a register is *overwritten* when new data arrives. Therefore, only the LEA instruction affects this result.

Moreover, the LEA instruction is special: it does not dereference the address it computes. In your example, because BP contains 4000h, the address the LEA computes is 4000h + 1000h == 5000h. The last address *is not used,* but is merely stored for future use in the AX register.

Therefore, at the end of this code's execution, the register AX will hold the value 5000h.

To clarify, I did not say that the register AX will hold a copy of the datum stored in memory at address 5000h. Rather, I said something simpler: the register AX will hold the value 5000h.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. They still use this old 8086 mode in Linux bootloaders. I have not encountered this mode elsewhere in a long time (and, anyway, back then, I was into Z80, 6502 and 68000, not 8086, admittedly), but who knows? The answer of @MichaelPetch looks good, at any rate.

Comment: Apparently some schools teach assembly language using emu8086 and DOS "system calls".  For some reason they think that older means simpler, and thus teach students real-mode segmentation because of a historical accident.  (That the CPU which caught on for our desktops happened to have its first generation during the transition from 16-bit address spaces to larger ones.)  So x86-16 real-mode is *vastly* over-represented in SO questions.  There are also people who want to "write their own OS" or be more "low level", but think that BIOS `int 0x10` calls are lower level than Linux system calls.

Comment: I learned x86 with 32-bit and 64-bit asm in user-space on Linux, with a flat memory model, and only later learned about the complexities of segmentation.  Much easier to learn that later once you understand the basics, and understand the problem that segmentation was designed to solve.